# Polymer core-icons does not render in FireFox

Tags: html, css, icons, polymer, material-design

I am using Ploymer icons 0.5.5 installed with bower. These Icons work fine in Chrome but are hidden in Firefox. [Example Code](https://s-a.github.io/TRY.js/)

How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that in your code you have not included the polyfill for Web Components, that's most likely the problem. No other browser supports web components like Chrome so you would have to include the polyfill like so in your `index.html`:

```
<script src="[Polymer-elements-folder]/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"><script>
```

Comment: It is showing up when the page gets refreshed for the first time and immediately disappears. I have the js referenced in my index.html file